# How to use Nhibernate Validator + NHib component + ddl

Tags: components, ddl, nhibernate-validator

I just configured my NHibValidator. My NHibernate creates the DB
schema. When I set MaxLenght="20" to some property of a class then in
the database the length appears in the database column. I am doing
this in the NHibValidator xml file. But the problem is that I have
components and cannot figure out how to achieve this behaviour. The
component is configured correctly in the Customer.hbm.xml file.

EDIT:
Well, I found that Hibernate Validator users had the same problem two 
years ago. 
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HV-25 
Is this an issue for NHibernate Validator or it is fixed. If it is 
working tell me how please.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
public class Customer
{
public virtual string Name{get;set;}
public virtual Contact Contacts{ get; }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
public class Contact
{
public virtual string Address{get;set;}
}
-----------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nhv-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-validator-1.0"
                        namespace="MyNamespace"
                        assembly="MyAssembly">
<class name="Customer">

   <property name="Name">
     <length max="20"/>
   </property>

   <property name="Contacts">
         <notNull/>
         <valid/>
   </property>

</class>
</nhv-mapping>
-----------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nhv-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-validator-1.0"
                        namespace="MyNamespace"
                        assembly="MyAssembly">
<class name="Contact">

   <property name="Address">
         <length max="50"/>
         <valid/>
   </property>

</class>
</nhv-mapping>
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this should be a bug. I posted this to NHibernate issue tracker.

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHV-82

UPDATE: the issue is solved.